# Jquery selecting span is not working

Tags: jquery, html

I have this in my code

```
<div class="prof-infos">Email:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>blahblah@email.com&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span class="change">change</span></div>
```

and I have this

```
$(".change").click(function() {
   alert("bloop");
});
```

however when I click the span; it doesn't do anything.

SOLUTION

use this instead

```
$(document).on("click", ".change", function() {
   alert("why does this work?");
});
```

Comment: by the way I have multiple spans with class of "change"

Comment: is the HTML that you posted present in the page from the moment the page is served or is it dynamically inserted to the DOM later on?

Comment: definitely inserted later through ajax

Comment: That's what I tough. That's why you can't attach it to the element. I'll expand in an answer below.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I thik you have missed jquery library, its working here ,check the above snippet

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```js
$(".change").click(function() {
   alert("bloop");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<div class="prof-infos">Email:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>blahblah@email.com&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span class="change">change</span></div>
```

you can use like this

```
$(document).on('click','.change',function(){
   /*Your code*/
});
```

```js
$(document).on('click','.change',function(){
   alert("bloop");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <div class="prof-infos">Email:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>blahblah@email.com&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span class="change">change</span></div>
```

Comment: try this , i have added one more snippet

Comment: $(document).on('click','.change',function(){
alert("hai");
}

Comment: fine!! keep coding :-)

Comment: do you think this solution works because I am loading information such as ".change" with ajax after the document has been loaded?

Comment: Yes, definitely the fact that the second solution works and your original doesn't is related with the fact that they get loaded later. Please read answer below.

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly. Can you post any other additional details and please import Jquery library in case you forgot to import it.

[JS Fiddle link][1]
 https://jsfiddle.net/c7m1b4ke/

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.js"></script>
<div class="prof-infos">Email:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>blahblah@email.com&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span class="change">change</span></div>

$( ".change" ).click(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
});
```

Comment: someone else fixed it. I had to use $(document).on() for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, you are trying to attach the click handler directly to the span elements, but like you said in the comments, those spans are fetched later on from an ajax call, so they aren't there by the time the page loads. You cannot attach an event handler to something that doesn't even exist yet.

The reason why the second example works is because you are using event delegation, i.e. you are attaching the click handler to the document element, which is the root of the DOM and does exist from the start.

JQuery implements a pattern know as event bubbling, which means that some events will travel up through the DOM tree from the element where they were originated to its parent, then to the parent's parent and so on until it either it is handled by some of these and the propagation stopped, or until it reaches the root of the DOM (document).

Of course this bubbling has some price on the efficiency of your page, so it's not recommended to attach the handler to the root. Instead attach it to the closest ancestor of your spans that exists from the beginning (maybe some container div). This way the event doesn't need to keep travelling up.

For more information about this, take a look at

[http://elijahmanor.com/differences-between-jquery-bind-vs-live-vs-delegate-vs-on/](http://elijahmanor.com/differences-between-jquery-bind-vs-live-vs-delegate-vs-on)

https://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events